# Material UI - How to open Dialog imperatively/programmatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Normally this is how you use Material UI [`Dialog`](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#dialog). The code below is taken from the docs:

```
export default function AlertDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
        Open Dialog
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
       {...}
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But I want it to create the `Dialog` imperatively, sort of like fire and forget. I do not want to *embed* the `Dialog` component in other components whenever I need to create them. Ideally I'd want to call it like this

```
createDialog(<>
   <h1>My Dialog</h1>
   <span>My dialog content</span>
   <button onClick={() => closeDialog()}>Close</button>
</>)
```

So my component definition'd look like this

```
const createDialog = () => {
   // ???
}
const closeDialog = () => {
   // ???
}
export default function AlertDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickOpen = () => setOpen(true);
  const handleClose = () => {
     createDialog(<>
        <h1>My Dialog</h1>
        <span>My dialog content</span>
        <button onClick={() => closeDialog()}>Close</button>
     </>)
  };

  return (
    <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
      Open Dialog
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can reuse dialogs using React's [`Provider`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) pattern. The official React document has explained in good detail so I won't cover it again here.

First create a custom `Provider` component in this case I'll call `DialogProvider`. This component will manage a list of `Dialog`s in local state.

```
const DialogContext = React.createContext();

export default function DialogProvider({ children }) {
  const [dialogs, setDialogs] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <DialogContext.Provider {...}>
      {children}
    </DialogContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

As you can see, we have an array of dialogs here, it contains the dialog props that will be mapped to the actually `<Dialog />` component when rendering.

```
export default function DialogProvider({ children }) {
  const [dialogs, setDialogs] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <DialogContext.Provider {...}>
      {children}
      {dialogs.map((dialog, i) => {
        return <DialogContainer key={i} {...dialog} />;
      })}
    </DialogContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The `<DialogContainer/>` is the parent component of the `<Dialog/>`. **Put anything that you want to be reusable in there**. Here is a minimum example to get you started.

```
function DialogContainer(props: DialogContainerProps) {
  const { children, open, onClose, onKill } = props;

  return (
    <Dialog open={open} onClose={onClose} onExited={onKill}>
      {children}
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

We can create and remove the dialog using `setState` as normal.

```
const [dialogs, setDialogs] = React.useState([]);

const createDialog = (option) => {
  const dialog = { ...option, open: true };
  setDialogs((dialogs) => [...dialogs, dialog]);
};

const closeDialog = () => {
  setDialogs((dialogs) => {
    const latestDialog = dialogs.pop();
    if (!latestDialog) return dialogs;
    if (latestDialog.onClose) latestDialog.onClose();
    return [...dialogs].concat({ ...latestDialog, open: false });
  });
};
```

But how do we call them in other components when we defined them here? Well, remember we're using `Provider` component here, which means we can pass the context data down so other components can reference, in this case we want to pass the `createDialog` and `closeDialog` down.

```
const [dialogs, setDialogs] = React.useState([]);
const createDialog = (option) => {/*...*/};
const closeDialog = () => {/*...*/};
const contextValue = React.useRef([createDialog, closeDialog]);

return (
  <DialogContext.Provider value={contextValue.current}>
    {children}
    {dialogs.map((dialog, i) => ...)}
  </DialogContext.Provider>
);
```

We're almost done here, now we need to add the `DialogProvider` to the component tree.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <DialogProvider>
      <App {...} />
    </DialogProvider>
  );
}
```

But before we can use them, we should create a hook to easily access the context from the parent. So in your `DialogProvider.jsx`

```
export const useDialog = () => React.useContext(DialogContext);
```

Now we can use it like this.

```
import { useDialog } from "./DialogProvider";

export default function Content() {
  const [openDialog, closeDialog] = useDialog();
  const onOpenDialog = () => {
    openDialog({
      children: (
        <>
          <DialogTitle>This dialog is opened imperatively</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>Some content</DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={closeDialog}>Close</Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </>
      )
    });
  };

  return (
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={onOpenDialog}>
      Show dialog
    </Button>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

You can play around in the live demo here

[image: Edit DialogProvider]

Comment: Awesome answer :) I searched for existing implementations online, found this package that worked well for me: https://github.com/Quernest/mui-modal-provider

Comment: Also a good one https://github.com/eBay/nice-modal-react

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But you are storing ReactNode (children prop) in state. Is it a good idea?

Comment: Note: you must replace `<Dialog onExited={..}` with `<Dialog TransitionProps={{onExited: ...}}` (at least in MUI v5), because the dialogs array will grow indefinitely otherwise (in other words: will leak).