# Idiomatic way to handle Message Alerts state in React and Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui, use-effect, use-state

I basically am building a web application using react and material UI. I have a registration form.

When this registration form successfully submits, it should display a success message at the top of the page.

Now, I have cordoned off the top of every page to show the `MyAlert` component. I have done this to make my site more consistent. Basically whenever there is a message to show to the user, it will render there.

Now, the issue is once the message is shown, if I navigate around my site, there is no way to turn it off.

Could someone please help explain what the best way to show a message once, then hide it would be? Basically once the user registers successfully, show a success message. Once the user navigates to a new page, hide the message at the top until a new message needs to be shown.

I imagine this is a very common design pattern, so I must be missing something in terms of React knowledge. Even best practice design patterns, or links to how it can be handled would be appreciated.

My toy app looks as follows:

**App.jsx**

```
    import * as React from 'react'
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

    import { Alert } from '@material-ui/lab'
    import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu'
    import {
        Button,
        AppBar,
        Toolbar,
        IconButton,
        Typography,
        makeStyles,
        Container,
    } from '@material-ui/core'

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
        root: {
            flexGrow: 1,
        },
        menuButton: {
            marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        },
        title: {
            flexGrow: 1,
        },
    }))

    const Navbar = (props) => {
        const classes = useStyles()
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar position="static">
                    <Toolbar>
                        <IconButton
                            edge="start"
                            className={classes.menuButton}
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="menu"
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                            <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to={'/'}>
                                My App
                            </Button>
                        </Typography>
                        <Button color="inherit" component={Link} to={'/register'}>
                            Register
                        </Button>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const Register = (props) => {
        const classes = useStyles()
        const { setShowAlert, setAlertMessage, setAlertSeverity } = props

        useEffect(() => {
            console.log('use effected')
        }, [])

        const handleRegistration = () => {
            setAlertMessage(
                'You have succesfully registered! Please check your email for a verification link.'
            )
            setAlertSeverity('success')
            setShowAlert(true)
        }

        return (
            <Container maxWidth="sm" align="center" className={classes.root}>
                This is some kind of form. I have redacted all input fields to
                illustrate the issue more clearly.<br></br>
                <Button
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    onClick={handleRegistration}
                >
                    Register
                </Button>
            </Container>
        )
    }

    const MyAlert = (props) => {
        const { severity, message } = props
        return <Alert severity={severity}>{message}</Alert>
    }

    const App = () => {
        const [alertSeverity, setAlertSeverity] = useState('')
        const [alertMessage, setAlertMessage] = useState('')
        const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false)

        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="app">
                    <Navbar />
                    <div>{showAlert ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
                    {showAlert ? (
                        <MyAlert severity={alertSeverity} message={alertMessage} />
                    ) : (
                        ''
                    )}
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            path="/register"
                            render={(props) => (
                                <Register
                                    {...props}
                                    setShowAlert={setShowAlert}
                                    setAlertMessage={setAlertMessage}
                                    setAlertSeverity={setAlertSeverity}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }

    export default App
```

**index.jsx**

```
import * as React from "react"
import { render } from "react-dom"
import App from './App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't that just be the case of using a setTimeout? When MyAlert is rendered, show it for 5 seconds and then dismiss.

First, pass it as a prop to your component (I also proposed a slightly different conditional render):

```
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="app">
                    <Navbar />
                    <div>{showAlert ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
                    {showAlert && 
                        <MyAlert severity={alertSeverity} message={alertMessage} setShowAlert = {setShowAlert}/> }
                    
                    <Switch>
                        <Route
                            path="/register"
                            render={(props) => (
                                <Register
                                    {...props}
                                    setShowAlert={setShowAlert}
                                    setAlertMessage={setAlertMessage}
                                    setAlertSeverity={setAlertSeverity}
                                />
                            )}
                        />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
```

Then in your MyAlert component, use useEffect to trigger a timeout:

```
  const MyAlert = (props) => {
   useEffect(() => {
     const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
       props.setShowAlert(false);  // Disable your alert after 5 seconds
      }, 5000);

     return () => {
       clearTimeout(timeout); // Clears timer in case you close your alert somewhere else.
     }
   }, [])
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Thales, would there be an easy way to make the notification persistent? I think you have a good approach, just wondering if you ever used a persistent approach

Comment: What do you mean with persistent? Across sessions? Across screens?

Comment: Yes across screens. So that when the user navigates away, the alert disappears. I am not sure if this is the standard way it is done on websites though.

Comment: Looking at how your code is structured at the moment, I'd say the alert would not disappear. Since you're rendering and controlling your alert state at the top level (same level as your router), when your router navigates your alert shoud persist across screens. Is that not the behavior you're getting? If you render MyAlert inside Register, then it should NOT persist, I believe

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I may need to render the alert in the page, rather than at the top-level of the app, it seems to work when I do that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Alright, glad I helped :) Top level should work fine as well. You could also look into Context API and Hooks to make your alert available at all levels of your app. Good luck, buddy.

Comment: @finite_diffidence If you ever decide to control the alert state at the app level. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63737527/9449426) to setup `Alert` using React Context. You can also create nested dialog using my solution.